# How to convert from one date format to another, in Microsoft SQL server?

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a date that is stored in 'MM/DD/YYYY' (101) format and I would like to convert it to 'DD/MM/YYYY' (103).  The source date (date in 101 format) is stored as a varchar initially, so I am guessing you would first need to convert it to a date type before changing it's format.

So practically my question is, "how do you change the format of a date stored as a varchar?".

Comment: **WHY** is it stored as a `VARCHAR` if it's a `DATETIME` ???

Answer (score 4):

try this...

```
select CONVERT(varchar(10), CONVERT(datetime, '12/31/2011', 101), 103)
```

Comment: In the end I want to have a value of type DATE.  So what I did, I wrapped the entire conversion with a CAST, but the result was a date in YYYY-MM-DD format.

Comment: SELECT CAST(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), CONVERT(DATETIME, '12/31/2011',101),103) AS DATE)

Comment: but this answers your original requirement, right? 

So practically my question is, "how do you change the format of a date stored as a varchar?".

Answer (score 2):

if you want to have a value of type DATE, you don't need to wrap the entire conversion with another CAST. you can just convert/cast it directly like

```
select CONVERT(date, CONVERT(datetime, '12/31/2011', 101))
```

or

```
select CONVERT(date, '12/31/2011', 101)
```

Answer (score 1):

[CAST and CONVERT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) are your friends here. Take a look at the date format codes in particular.

Comment: So practically I was importing data from an excel file to a database table, using an SSIS package.  So I made every column in the import table to be of type varchar(250), to avoid conversion issues between SSIS and SQL.

Answer (score 0):

I used Leon Tayson's answer to fix a field with mixed date formats, using codes from this location:
https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1145/date-and-time-conversions-using-sql-server/

```
/**MM-DD-YYYY to YYYY-MM-DD **/
UPDATE [DBO].[TABLE]
   SET [DATEFIELD] = CONVERT(varchar(10), CONVERT(datetime, DATEFIELD, 110), 23)
where DATEFIELD like '__-__-____'

/** excel date serial number to YYYY-MM-DD **/
UPDATE [DBO].[TABLE]
   SET [DATEFIELD] = dateadd(DAY, convert(bigint, DATEFIELD) , convert(date, '1-1-1900'))
 Where Len(UPDATED_DATE) = 5

/** YYYY to YYYY-MM-DD **/
UPDATE [DBO].[TABLE]
SET [DATEFIELD] = DATEFIELD + '-01-01'
Where Len(DATEFIELD) = 4
```