# Convert dd/mm/yyy to mm/dd/yyy T-SQL 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have write this proc

```
   alter proc vencedata (@inicio smalldatetime)as
   select idconta,vencimento,pagamento,historico,original,formpagto,planoconta,clifor 
   from financeiro where vencimento >=  @inicio
```

the column vencimento(smalldatetime) is in the format mm/dd/yyyy  the proc works in this format

```
  vencedata '03/28/2013' (mm/dd/yyyy)
```

but the date for @inicio comes in dd/mm/yyyy  i need the proc works
      vencedata '28/03/2013'

i have try with convert but i don write right
Thanks by any orientation

Comment: is it a varchar column?

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7991872/how-to-convert-from-one-date-format-to-another-in-microsoft-sql-server or the [SQL SERVER CAST and CONVERT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx)

Answer (score 4):

Use [`CONVERT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) with style parameter

To get SMALLDATETIME from VARCHAR

```sql
-- From Europe style varchar
DECLARE @d1 VARCHAR(20) = '28/03/2013'
SELECT CONVERT(smalldatetime, @d1, 103)
-- From American style varchar
DECLARE @d2 VARCHAR(20) = '03/28/2013'
SELECT CONVERT(smalldatetime, @d2, 101)
```

In both cases output is

```
2013-03-28 00:00:00
```

And vice versa from SMALLDATETIME to VARCHAR

```sql
DECLARE @d3 SMALLDATETIME = '2013-03-28'
-- To Europe style
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), @d3, 103)
-- To American style 
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), @d3, 101)
```

Ouput

```
28/03/2013
03/28/2013
```

Comment: obrigado man. salvou meu dia aqui.

Answer (score 1):

Date, Datetime  don't have formats as you say but your issue is that server fails to convert your string of `dd/mm/yyyy` format to a `smalldatetime`.

If date is passing as string in `dd/mm/yyyy` format, best thing is to get it to ***ISO format*** (`yyyymmdd`) and then convert to smalldatetime before passing to the stored procedure.

```
declare @inicio varchar(20) = '28/03/2013',
        @inicio_date smalldatetime

select @inicio_date = convert(smalldatetime,
               right(@inicio,4) + right(left(@inicio,5),2) + left(@inicio,2))
```

Execute stored procedure as below;

```
exec vencedata @inicio_date
```

[Fiddle demo of convertion](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/9622)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
-- =============================================
-- Author:      RAFAŁ :D
-- Create date: <Create Date,,>
-- Description: <Description,,>
-- =============================================
CREATE PROCEDURE Esample
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @vencedata datetime
    SET @vencedata = convert(datetime, '03/28/2013')
    DECLARE @data datetime
    SET @data = convert(datetime, (Convert(varchar(60),Month(@vencedata))+'/'+Convert(varchar(60),DAY(@vencedata))+'/'++Convert(varchar(60),YEAR(@vencedata))))
    SELECT @data
END
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

C# convert fine the date the problema was in the 00:00:00 fo datetime when compare whit smalldatetime

```
  string inicio = dateTimePicker1.Value.ToShortDateString();
  string fim = dateTimePicker2.Value.ToShortDateString(); 
  DateTime Dinicio = Convert.ToDateTime(inicio); 
  DateTime Dfinal =  convert.ToDateTime(fim);
           Decimal Svt = minaf.TData(Dinicio, Dfinal); 
           DataTable llena3 = minaf.cargrid3(Dinicio,Dfinal);
```

the trick is convert to short date string.